# Why is the second cardView is not visible?

Tags: android, firebase

I face a problem when I try to run the app on my phone. The first cardView is visible but in second card view is not visible. The app will draw the information and display on the cardView. May I know what is the reason that causing this issue? I have tried to resize the card size in my XML, but it seems that it doesn't work. Thank you.

[image: cardView problem]

Code in adapter:

```
Context context;
    List<ViewAllModel> viewAllModelList;

    public ViewAllAdapter(Context context, List<ViewAllModel> viewAllModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.viewAllModelList = viewAllModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_all_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(viewAllModelList.get(position).getImg_url()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.name.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getName());
        holder.description.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.price.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getPrice() + "/kg");
        holder.rating.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getRating());

        if(viewAllModelList.get(position).getType().equals("egg")){
            holder.price.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getPrice() + "/dozen");
        }
        if(viewAllModelList.get(position).getType().equals("milk")){
            holder.price.setText(viewAllModelList.get(position).getPrice()+" /litre");
        }

        //Detail will be shown after user click on the item card.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailedActivity.class);
                //pass detail to another activity, serializable is implemented in viewAllModel.
                intent.putExtra("detail", viewAllModelList.get(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return viewAllModelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name, description, price, rating;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_img);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_name);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_des);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_price);
            rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_rating);

        }
    }
```

```
Get fruit
        if(type != null && type.equalsIgnoreCase("fruit")){
            firestore.collection("AllProducts").whereEqualTo("type", "fruit").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                        ViewAllModel viewAllModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(ViewAllModel.class);
                        viewAllModelList.add(viewAllModel);
                        viewAllAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: It looks like your first `CardView` is cut off too. I think you've either hard-coded a height for one of your `View`s or you need to use `MATCH_PARENT` somewhere instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` for the height. But it's hard to tell because you haven't included any layout code or shown where you instantiated your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Please include your layout code. I think the issue coming from your layout

Comment: My Be You set your  XML view_all_item view Height to "match_parent " change match_parent to warap_content

Comment: I found out that the layout CardView height is accidentally set to match parent, now the problem solved, thank you for solution.